# Is it a matter of precision or just wrongly typed syntax?

Tags: syntax, integer, transform, precision

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e") && transform.rotation.y == (int)0.0f)
    {
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(0,(int)-80,0f);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown("f") && transform.rotation.y == (int)-80.0f)
    {
        gameObject.transform.Rotate(0,(int)-160,0f);
    }
```

So i do want the object to rotate. It rotates when i press e, but it doesn't do anything when i press f. I tried to convert it to int instead of float but it doesn't work either. Any ideas? thank you. Im a beginner.

Comment: Can you please add details such as what framework are using, what platform, etc?

Comment: It's Unity so i think C++

Comment: Ok, Unity is probably C#. Are you sure this part of the if is correct?

&& transform.rotation.y == (int)-80.0f

You can verify that by putting a break point